# Detect which attributes were called in `update` in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to detect which attributes were included in an `update` call in rails even if those attributes don't change?  The `after_update` callback is still called but since nothing has actually changed `ActiveModel::Dirty` doesn't seem to have any methods that will detect the relevant attributes.

Example:

I have a `user` model which has column `notification_hour` which defaults to `9`

I call `User.update(notification_hour: 9)`

This triggers the callback
`after_update :set_time_flag`

I would like to set that the user has at least set the time even though they've set it to the same as the default.

```
def set_time_flag
  return unless notification_hour_changed?

  update_column(notifiation_time_set: true)
end
```

This will return without setting the flag since the value didn't change.  Is there a way to detect that `update` was called with `notification_hour` even though it didn't actually change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update a record, it executes a setter method for each attribute being updated.

`update(notification_hour: 9)` will execute `notification_hour=(9)`

So, you can play with it. Just overload the method to detect if the attribute was set:

```
after_update :set_time_flag

def notification_hour=(hour)
  @notification_hour_was_set = true
  super
end

private

def set_time_flag
  if @notification_hour_was_set
      update_column(notifiation_time_set: true)
  end
end
```

**Updated**

SteveTurczyn's answer gave me the better idea. You don't really need the `after_update` callback and extra update. Just set `notifiation_time_set` to `true` when `notification_hour` is set:

```
def notification_hour=(hour)
  self.notification_time_set = true
  super
end
```

Comment: nice! that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def update(changes={})
    changes[:notification_time_set] = true if changes.key?(:notification_hour)
    super(changes)
  end
end
```